# UnexpectedRecordException: End of stream reached, expected record 'batchControl' while parsing in BeanIO

Tags: spring-boot, parsing, mainframe, bean-io, fixed-length-record

I'm trying to come up with the configuration to be able to parse a feed file coming from the mainframe (fixed-length).

Given the fact that the first position of every line of that feed represents a record type, I'm trying to build a minimal skeleton for a **BeanIO (2.1)** configuration (just the 1st field of every record for now) to represent that file's format.

**The sample file to parse** (just the 1st field of every line/record, for now):

```
1
5
6
6
6
8
5
6
8
9
```

While running the BeanIO unmarshaller to parse above minimal mainframe file format, the following exception is being thrown:

```
org.beanio.UnexpectedRecordException: End of stream reached, expected record 'batchControl'
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.UnmarshallingContext.newUnsatisfiedRecordException(UnmarshallingContext.java:367)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.unmarshal(Group.java:127)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.DelegatingParser.unmarshal(DelegatingParser.java:39)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.RecordCollection.unmarshal(RecordCollection.java:42)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.Group.unmarshal(Group.java:140)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanReaderImpl.internalRead(BeanReaderImpl.java:106)
    at org.beanio.internal.parser.BeanReaderImpl.read(BeanReaderImpl.java:67)
    at com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.acquire.provider.sftp.unmarshal.AchFileUnmarshallerService.unmarshalAchReturnFile(AchFileUnmarshallerService.java:76)
    at com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.acquire.provider.sftp.unmarshal.AchFileUnmarshallerServiceTest.testSuccessfulUnmarshallingOfMinimalFileToSkeletonAchObjectGraph(AchFileUnmarshallerServiceTest.java:175)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Here are the relevant files:

**AchFileUnmarshallerService.java**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class AchFileUnmarshallerService {

    public static final String BEANIO_PARSER_FORMAT = "fixedlength";
    public final static String UNMARSHALLER_STREAM_NAME = "sftp-ach";
    
    public AchFileCollection unmarshalAchReturnFile(File filetoParse, StreamBuilder streamBuilder){
        Assert.notNull(filetoParse, "A valid file must be provided for parsing.");
        Assert.state(Files.exists(filetoParse.toPath()), "A valid ACH file must exist at the provided path to attempt parsing.");
        
        String fileName = filetoParse.getAbsolutePath();
        
        log.info("Starting unmarshaling '{}' to a corresponding ACH structure.", fileName);
        
//      StreamBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamBuilder(UNMARSHALLER_STREAM_NAME)
//              .format(BEANIO_PARSER_FORMAT)
//              .parser(new FixedLengthParserBuilder())
//              .addGroup(AchFileCollection.class)
//              .occurs(1, -1)
//              //.strict()
//              ;
        
        StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
        factory.define(streamBuilder);
        
        BeanReader beanioReader = factory.createReader(UNMARSHALLER_STREAM_NAME, fileName);
        /*
        beanioReader.setErrorHandler(new BeanReaderErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleError(BeanReaderException ex) throws Exception {

                for (int i = 0; i < ex.getRecordCount(); i++) {
                    RecordContext context = ex.getRecordContext(i);
                    log.info(context.toString());
                }

                throw new BeanReaderException(ex.toString(), ex);
            }

        });
        */
        
        return (AchFileCollection)beanioReader.read();
    }
    
}
```

**AchFileUnmarshallerServiceTest.java**

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(classes = { 
        DcrDataFactoryApplication.class,
        /* FileAcquisitionConfig.class, */ 
        /* FileDistributionConfig.class */
        })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "application.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
@Slf4j
class AchFileUnmarshallerServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private AchFileUnmarshallerService achFileUnmarshallerService;
    
    
    private StreamBuilder streamBuilder() {
        StreamBuilder streamBuilder = new StreamBuilder(AchFileUnmarshallerService.UNMARSHALLER_STREAM_NAME)
                .format(AchFileUnmarshallerService.BEANIO_PARSER_FORMAT).minOccurs(1)
                .addGroup(new GroupBuilder("achFile").type(AchFile.class).order(1).occurs(1, -1)
                        .addRecord(new RecordBuilder("fileHeader", AchFileHeader.class).order(1).occurs(1, 1)
                                .addField(new FieldBuilder("recordTypeCode").at(0).length(1).required().literal("1")))
                        .addGroup(new GroupBuilder("batchRecords").type(AchBatch.class).order(2).occurs(0, -1)
                                .collection(List.class)
                                .addRecord(new RecordBuilder("batchHeader", AchBatchHeader.class).order(1).occurs(1, 1)
                                        .addField(new FieldBuilder("recordTypeCode").at(0).length(1).required()
                                                .literal("5")))
                                .addRecord(new RecordBuilder("batchEntries", AchBatchEntry.class).order(2).occurs(0, -1)
                                        .collection(List.class)
                                        .addField(new FieldBuilder("recordTypeCode").at(0).length(1).required()
                                                .literal("6")))
                                .addRecord(new RecordBuilder("batchControl", AchBatchFooter.class).order(3).occurs(1, 1)
                                        .addField(new FieldBuilder("recordTypeCode").at(0).length(1).required()
                                                .literal("8"))))
                        .addRecord(new RecordBuilder("fileControl", AchFileFooter.class).order(3).occurs(1, 1)
                                .addField(new FieldBuilder("recordTypeCode").at(0).length(1).required().literal("9"))))

        ;
        return streamBuilder;
    }
    
    @Test 
    @SneakyThrows
    void testSuccessfulUnmarshallingOfMinimalFileToSkeletonAchObjectGraph() {
        log.info("Ready to unmarshall.");
        
        File fileToUnmarshall = new ClassPathResource("skeleton.ach.file.txt").getFile();
        
        AchFileCollection root =  achFileUnmarshallerService.unmarshalAchReturnFile(fileToUnmarshall, streamBuilder());
        
        log.info("Finished unmarshalling {} file into the following structure {}.", fileToUnmarshall.getName(), root);
    }
```

Domain model classes (with records containing just a single field, as explained earlier):

**AchFile.java**:

```
@Data
//@Group
public class AchFile {

    //@Record
    private AchFileHeader fileHeader;
    //@Group
    private List<AchBatch> batchRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    //@Record
    private AchFileFooter fileControl;
}
```

**AchFileFooter.java:**

```
@Data
public class AchFileFooter {

    //@Field(name = "recordTypeCode", ordinal = 1, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal="9")
    private String recordTypeCode;
    
}
```

**AchFileHeader.java:**

```
@Data
public class AchFileHeader {

    //@Field(name = "recordTypeCode", ordinal = 1, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal="1")
    private String recordTypeCode;
}
```

**AchFileCollection.java** (for now, unused):

```
@Data
//@Group(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = -1)
public class AchFileCollection {

    //@Group
    private List<AchFile> achFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    
}
```

**AchBatch.java:**

```
@Data
//@Group
public class AchBatch {
    //@Record
    private AchBatchHeader batchHeader;
    //@Record
    private List<AchBatchEntry> batchEntries = new ArrayList<>();
    //@Record
    private AchBatchFooter batchControl;
}
```

**AchBatchHeader.java:**

```
@Data
//@Record(order = 1, minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = 1)
public class AchBatchHeader {

    //@Field(name = "recordTypeCode", ordinal = 1, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal="5")
    private String recordTypeCode;
}
```

**AchBatchFooter.java:**

```
@Data
//@Record(order = 3, minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = 1)
public class AchBatchFooter {

    //@Field(name = "recordTypeCode", ordinal = 1, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal="8")
    private String recordTypeCode;
    
}
```

**AchBatchEntry.java:**

```
@Data
//@Record(order = 2, minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
public class AchBatchEntry {
    
    //@Field(name = "recordTypeCode", ordinal = 1, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal="6")
    private String recordTypeCode;
}
```

N.B.: eventually, when I add more fields on each record type, the configuration will migrate into the domain model (hence the annotations there, commented for now).  Wanted to first get it via BeanIO's Java builders option, all in one place, for testing.

My assumption is once `BeanReader` is configured with input topology via `StreamFactory` and given the input data to process (in a form of a file) it would match the two together and would know how to iterate the lines of the input file while recognizing types of records they represent, build the resulting output object representation of that input file and return it properly hydrated.  Or is it too optimistic and not how BeanIO reader works and I need to do something else manually?

What am I doing wrong to get the above exception and how do I straighten it out?

Answer (score 0):

I gradually moved the relevant mappings from the Java builders style shown above to the annotations one shown below (mysteriously, some of them are not relevant in annotations, it's not a 1-to-1 correspondence somehow):

**AchFile.java:**

```
@Data
@Group(name = "achFile", /* order = 1, */ minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = -1)  //.order(2).occurs(1, -1)
public class AchFile {


    @Record( minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
    private AchFileHeader fileHeader;

    @Group( minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
    private Set<AchBatch> batchRecords = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
    @Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
    private AchFileFooter fileControl;
}
```

**AchFileHeader.java:**

```
@Data
@Record(order = 1, minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1) 
public class AchFileHeader {
    
    @Field( ordinal = 1, rid = true, at = 0, length = 1, required = true, literal = "1") 
    private String type;
}
```

**AchFileFooter.java:**

```
@Data
public class AchFileFooter {
    
    @Field( rid = true, at=0, length=1, required=true, literal="9")
    private String type;
    
}
```

**AchBatch.java:**

```
@Data
@Group(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
public class AchBatch {
    
    @Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
    private AchBatchHeader batchHeader;
    
    @Record(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
    private Set<AchBatchEntry> batchEntries = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    
    @Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
    private AchBatchFooter batchControl;
   
}
```

**AchBatchHeader.java:**

```
@Data
@Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
public class AchBatchHeader {
    
    @Field(name="type", rid=true, at=0, length=1, required=true, literal="5") 
    private String type;
    
}
```

**AchBatchFooter.java:**

```
@Data
@Record(minOccurs = 1, maxOccurs = 1)
public class AchBatchFooter {

    @Field(rid=true, at=0, length=1, required=true, literal="8") 
    private String type;
    
}
```

**AchBatchEntry.java:**

```
@Data
@Record(minOccurs = 0, maxOccurs = -1)
public class AchBatchEntry {

    @Field(rid=true, at=0, length=1, required = true, literal="6") 
    private String type;
    
}
```

and with the following runner:

```
        Assert.notNull(filetoParse, "A valid file must be provided for parsing.");
        Assert.state(Files.exists(filetoParse.toPath()), "A valid ACH file must exist at the provided path to attempt parsing.");
        
        String fileName = filetoParse.getAbsolutePath();
        
        log.info("Started unmarshalling '{}' according to the provided topology.", fileName);
        
        StreamFactory factory = StreamFactory.newInstance();
        factory.define(streamBuilder);
        
        BeanReader beanioReader = factory.createReader(AchTopologyFactory.UNMARSHALLER_STREAM_NAME, fileName);
        
        Set<T> result = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        T parsed;
        while ((parsed = (T) beanioReader.read()) != null) {
            result.add(parsed);
        }
        beanioReader.close();
        
        log.info("Finished unmarshaling '{}' to a corresponding ACH structure: {}", fileName, result);
        return result;
```

it started to produce the desired behavior.

```
Parsed struct: [AchFile(fileHeader=AchFileHeader(type=1), batchRecords=[AchBatch(batchHeader=AchBatchHeader(type=5), batchEntries=[AchBatchEntry(type=6)], batchControl=AchBatchFooter(type=8))], fileControl=AchFileFooter(type=9)), AchFile(fileHeader=AchFileHeader(type=1), batchRecords=[AchBatch(batchHeader=AchBatchHeader(type=5), batchEntries=[AchBatchEntry(type=6)], batchControl=AchBatchFooter(type=8)), AchBatch(batchHeader=AchBatchHeader(type=5), batchEntries=[], batchControl=AchBatchFooter(type=8))], fileControl=AchFileFooter(type=9)), AchFile(fileHeader=AchFileHeader(type=1), batchRecords=[], fileControl=AchFileFooter(type=9))]
```

given the following input:

```
1
5
6
6
6
8
5
6
8
9
1
5
8
5
6
8
5
8
9
1
9
1
5
8
5
6
8
5
8
9
```

As mentioned, it's unclear why certain combinations of attributes work in the Java builder style but not in the annotations style nor why the mix of styles don't seem to always work either - so an expert voice in BeanIO framework is certainly welcome to comment or challenge above working setup or open a corresponding ticket with the framework as a bug.